# JavaScript: Improve performance inside nested loops

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

how can I optimize the incredibly slow code shown below to speed? I think, JS converts the ints to floats and vise-versa all the time. How can I spot such performance killers? I think, there is much space left to optimize :-). I think, there is a better way to handle the nibble values.

At first, I tried to ditch the &15 operation for the higher nibble. That just slowed more down instead of speed up.

(The code is incomplete. It is just a part taken from a bigger one. It is filling a buffer for createBufferSource(). It should be processed an played as soon as possible after a click event. Currently, on a mobile, it takes up to 2s for an average audio file.)

```
for (var len = adpcm.length, i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    n = [
        adpcm.charCodeAt(i) & 15,
        (adpcm.charCodeAt(i) >> 4) & 15
    ];
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        s = n[j];
        stp = imaStepTable[index];
        diff = stp >> 3;
        if (s & 4) diff += stp;
        if (s & 2) diff += (stp >> 1);
        if (s & 1) diff += (stp >> 2);
        if (s & 8) diff = 0 - diff;
        pred += diff;
        if (pred > 32760) pred = 32760;
        else if (pred < -32760) pred = -32760; //limiter
        index += imaIndexTable[s];
        if (index < 0) index = 0;
        else if (index > 88) index = 88;
        for (var k = 0; k < sampleScale; k++) { //resampler
            if (!k) {
                lPcm[c] = pred / 32768;
                rPcm[c] = (c - shift) < 0 ? 0 : lPcm[(c - shift)];
            } else {
                lPcm[c] = lPcm[c - k];
                rPcm[c] = rPcm[c - k];
            }
            c++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably want to put this on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could try [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If this were posted on Code Review, we would ask for a title and description that actually explains what the code does / is meant for. That said, it would be on-topic on CR.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO, but [codereview.se] seems like it would be an excellent fit. I recommend deleting your post here before you accrue any downvotes and posting it on code review.

Comment: If available, try using a `UInt8Array` buffer instead of a string to hold your ADPCM samples.  Using `String.charCodeAt()` will be horribly inefficient, and you're calling it twice per iteration.  You should access the byte just _once_ and then split the nybbles.

Comment: If you want to get meaningful answers, you need to come up with an executable self-contained code sample and provide exemplary input over which performance can be tested in different JS engines.

Comment: @Alnitak Close because it's off-topic here. Whether it's on-topic for Code Review is quite irrelevant.

Comment: @Mast it is relevant - there's an explicit close reason (accessible at 3000 rep) that includes it being on-topic on other SE sites, although as it happens CR isn't one of the default ones listed.

Comment: @Alnitak There's a very, very good reason for that. Take a look at meta if you don't believe me.